# Trigger a pipeline on a every 2nd and 4th Tuesday of the month in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Azure DevOps that would trigger every every 2nd and 4th Tuesday of the month regardless if there are changes on the git branches. This is what I have, but it's not working.

```
trigger: none
pr: none

schedules:
 cron: '0 8 8-14,22-28 * 2'
 displayName: Trigger every 2nd and 4th Tuesday
 branches:
     include: 
     - develop
  always: true
```

It is working for this - cron: "*/5 * * * *"(triggering every 5 mintues) but above cron is not working.

Comment: Not sure if intentional, but the `always:true` isn't indented properly in the codeblock above.

Comment: Maybe this example can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33816674. At least it shows a different syntax on how to select second and/or fourth day of a month. So for the second tuesday it would be "2#2", for the fourth it would be "2#4".

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with just cron expression in Azure DevOps. This implementation doesn't support this

[image]

Take a look on issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/60342).

What you can do is to run every Monday and Tuesday and then in first job check if this is a 2nd or 4th. Based on that set variable and use that variable in condition to run or not a real job.

Answer (score -1):

This cron works for me

```
  - cron: 0 8 6-12,20-26  * 2
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: This definitely doesn't work as intended. It'll work for Sept/Oct this year but not in November. https://ncrontab.swimburger.net/?expression=0+8+6-12,20-26++*+2